# C++ GUI Tutorial: undefined reference to TextOut

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

So after a bit of searching for Win32 GUI tutorials (I decided a tutorial on making GUIs might make me more active in making C++ applications and therefore stronger at programming in C++ in general,) I came across a rohitab tutorial. There are two parts that I have been able to find. Part 1 worked fine, and I'm now working on [Part 2](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/index.php?showtopic=11454), however, I'm getting this error in Code::Blocks:

`C:\Users\John\Documents\Windows GUIs\first_gui.cpp||In function 'C:\Users\John\Documents\Windows GUIs\first_gui.o:first_gui.cpp:(.text+0x281)||undefined reference to '_TextOutA@20'|`

My code can be found <s>here</s> (broken link).

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Code won't help. Post your build command lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you link your app against `GDI32.LIB`?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't, and I don't have the library, so I'm just going to use a better tutorial I just found. Thanks. =]

Comment: If you have windows, then you don't need the library.  You can get the same result with statements in your .def file.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a linker error, are you linking to `gdi32.lib`?

Answer (score 0):

You should download a WINDOWS SDK package, this include all libraries that you will need to create programs with GDI (including gdi32);
Then in codeblocks/compiler/linkersettings choose folder where SDK's lib files are stored.
That's is it!!.