# Undefined reference to "boost::system::system_category()"

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks, undefined-reference

```
obj\Debug\src\SQLite3DB.o||In function _static_initialization_and_destruction_0:|
D:\workspace-cpp\boost_1_54_0_beta1\boost\system\error_code.hpp|222|undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()|
D:\workspace-cpp\boost_1_54_0_beta1\boost\system\error_code.hpp|223|undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()|
D:\workspace-cpp\boost_1_54_0_beta1\boost\system\error_code.hpp|224|undefined reference to boost::system::system_category()|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 4 seconds) ===|
```

Above is my full error message after including `boost/filesystem.hpp` to my project. I saw some posts which said that adding `-lboost_system` might solve this, but I have no idea where to do that in CodeBlocks!
I have already spent one day on solving this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

Comment: i just add the -lboost_system in the linker but it come out this error "No such file or dictory". What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project name; click "Build options..."; go to "Linker settings"; click "Add"; find the library and add it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Additionally, you may add some custom variables to ease the management of debug/release and 32/64bit target options. I'll leave that to you.

**EDIT**

Here is the erroneous code from `error_code.hpp`:

```
# ifndef BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
    inline const error_category &  get_system_category() { return system_category(); }
    inline const error_category &  get_generic_category() { return generic_category(); }
    inline const error_category &  get_posix_category() { return generic_category(); }
    static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
    static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
    static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
# endif
```

As you can see, defining `BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED` will disable it. I have tested that and it works. This compiles:

```
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

int main(void)
{

}
```

Comment: ..\..\..\..\Boost\1_54_0\VC\11.0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\msvc-11.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib -- after i adding this to linker setting it still getting the same error!