# Undefined reference when using windows.h

Tags: c++

I want to use the ChooseColor function in a console application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm using their sample code to test it out, and I have included windows.h like they told me, but I get the errors:

```
undefined reference to 'ChooseColorA@4'
undefined reference to 'CreateSolidBrush@4'
```

I'm using Code::Blocks, and I have tried including "Windows.h" and "Commdlg.h",  but without luck. Do I need to mess around with Linker settings just to use windows.h? My code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    CHOOSECOLOR cc;                 // common dialog box structure
    static COLORREF acrCustClr[16]; // array of custom colors
    HWND hwnd;                      // owner window
    HBRUSH hbrush;                  // brush handle
    static DWORD rgbCurrent;        // initial color selection

    // Initialize CHOOSECOLOR
    ZeroMemory(&cc, sizeof(cc));
    cc.lStructSize = sizeof(cc);
    cc.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    cc.lpCustColors = (LPDWORD) acrCustClr;
    cc.rgbResult = rgbCurrent;
    cc.Flags = CC_FULLOPEN | CC_RGBINIT;

    if (ChooseColor(&cc)==TRUE)
    {
        hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(cc.rgbResult);
        rgbCurrent = cc.rgbResult;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation of those functions. It should say: *Library: gdi32.lib* and *Library: comdlg32.lib*. Yes, linking is a good thing. It would take much longer than it already does to compile windows.h without.

Comment: Note also that you are testing the result of ChooseColor incorrectly. Read the documentation more closely.

Comment: What are you going to do with a brush in a console application?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the gdi32 library to your project so it links, not just include.

see: [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)