# Code::Blocks linking error

Tags: c++, c, winapi, codeblocks, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to use `windows.h` function `SetPixel()` in Code::Blocks but it gives me a linking error
`undefined reference to SetPixel@16`

How could I link the library functions to the project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the gdi32 library. There's an good answer here on SO that will tell you how to do this:
[How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881751/1175077)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-lgdi32` to the linker flags.