# Code::Blocks v12.11 include .lib to project

Tags: c++, codeblocks

How I can add a `Some.lib` file to my project in `Code::Blocks` 12.11 version?

I am tried to find linker options (Project, Building Options have a only Post/Prebuild steps, Custom Variables, "Make" commands). #pragma comment(lib, `xxx.lib`) - useless for GCC compiler, and the function from my lib file - `SFileOpenFileEx(file, szArchivedFile, 0, &hFile)` showed me the `error: not declared` (i.e. lib not working.)

How i can resolve this?

Source is:

```
#include "resourcemanager.h"
#include "filestream.h"

#include <physfs.h>
#include <archivelib> //mylib 

ResourceManager g_resources;

void ResourceManager::init(const char *argv0)
{
    PHYSFS_init(argv0);
    PHYSFS_permitSymbolicLinks(1);
}

void ResourceManager::terminate()
{
    PHYSFS_deinit();
}

//test function for library
bool ResourceManager::openArchive(const std::string& szArchiveName, const std::string& szArchivedFile, const std::string& szFileName)
{
    HANDLE hDat   = NULL;          // Open archive handle
    HANDLE hFile  = NULL;          // Archived file handle
    HANDLE handle = NULL;          // Disk file handle
    int    nError = ERROR_SUCCESS; // Result value

    //openArchive
    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if(!SFileOpenArchive(szArchiveName, 0, 0, &hDat))
            nError = GetLastError();
    }

    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if(!SFileOpenFileEx(hDat, szArchivedFile, 0, &hFile))
            nError = GetLastError();
    }

    //file opens, return true. just test.
    return true;
}
```

the error is Line: 340|error: ‘SFileOpenArchive’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: "Not declared" suggests you are missing an include rather than a library. What is the exact error message? What does the code look like?

Comment: added. SFileOpenArchive and SFileOpenFileEx is Library functions, but i dont have idea, how to make them work in Code::Blocks. In MSVS the solution is "pragma comment" but in this cause i dont have idea how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a compilation error, not a link error, so the problem has nothing to do with libraries. You need to make a declaration of the function visible, which is normally done by including a header.

If the `SFileOpenArchive` you want is the one in StormLib (which would be useful information to include in the question) then the [documentation](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/stormlib.html) clearly states that the header is StormLib.h, so you need to add

```
#include "StormLib.h"
```

to your program.

EDIT: If after that you have linking problems, see [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks).

Comment: thanks, ill check it. But theme about linking libs in Code::Blocks is outdated. And i am already add it, by Settings--->Compiler--->Linker Settings--->Add library. That actually works in 12.11ver