# Setting up freeglut in codeblocks

Tags: c++

I'm new to graphics in Windows.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I installed `mingw` and it seemed to work.

Then I downloaded `Codeblocks` and that seemed to work too.

Next I downloaded the `freeglut` package, unzipped it and copied all the files to the various locations.

When I tried to compile Tutorial 01 provided in `ogldev-source`, I got eleven error messages consisting of a series of undefined references such as:

```
undefined reference to '_imp_glutinit/windowsPosition@@'
undefined reference to 'glClearColor@16'
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to link the .dll and .libs to the compiler in code blocks
I would recommend you this post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks).

Comment: Its generally the same except you would , just link the name of your dlls or libs

Comment: Thanks very much.  The codeblocks screen looks somewhat different, but I managed to find the settings tab, and linked the library files.  I now get 2 error messages instead of 11.  But even after linking to all the .lib files I can find, I still cannot get rid of the 2 errors, which are undefined reference to 'glclear@4' and undefined reference to 'glclearcolor@16'.  I must be missing something.

Comment: That means you had a linking problem. I will recommend this article I found on the code block's website for the windows tutorial to install freeglut and make sure all the functions work. [link](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_FreeGlut_with_Code::Blocks)

Comment: I followed the excellent tutorial step by step, all seems fine except at the very end when I tried to run the sample code that came with freeglut, I again got two "undefined reference" errors.  I posted these errors on this site.  I'm kind of lost what to do next.  Appreciate your help.