# Passing objects to functions C++

Tags: c++, function, class, header-files

I'm having trouble unsing my AVL tree class in one of my programs, I'm not sure how to include my class and use it with existing code, here is the problem:

I have an AVL tree class: `AVL_tree.h` and `AVL_tree.cpp`

I also have a `main.cpp` file

Also `functions.cpp` and `functions.h`, where I store some functions used in `main.cpp`

So, in `main()` I create an object from my AVL tree class. I want to pass this object along with some other data (which will serve to change the information stored in the tree) to one of the functions from my `functions.cpp`. And here is where I can't get it to work. I get several errors like these ones:

```
main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `AVL_Tree::AVL_Tree()'|
main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `process_vector(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, AVL_Tree&)'|
```

How can I pass the necessary information to my function in order to modify my tree?

Simplified version of my code files:

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "functions.h"
#include "AVL_tree.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    AVL_Tree tree;
    vector<int> V;

    V.push_back(11);
    V.push_back(4);
    V.push_back(7);

    process_vector(V, tree);

    return 0;
}
```

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include<vector>
#include"AVL_tree.h"
using namespace std;

void process_vector(vector<int> V, AVL_Tree &tree);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H
```

functions.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include"functions.h"
#include"AVL_tree.h"
using namespace std;

void process_vector(vector<int> V, AVL_Tree &tree){
    for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++){
        key = vector[i]
        tree.AddLeaf(key);
    }
    return;
}
```

AVL_tree.h

```
#ifndef AVL_TREE_H
#define AVL_TREE_H

class AVL_Tree{

private:
    struct node{
        int key;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;
    node* CreateLeaf(int key);
    node* AddLeafPrivate(int key, node* Ptr);
    int HeightPrivate(node* Ptr);
    int BFactorPrivate(node* Ptr);

public:
    AVL_Tree();
    void AddLeaf(int key);
    int Height(int key);
    int BFactor(int key);

};

#endif // TREE
```

Comment: It looks like you have a link problem.  How are you building your program?

Comment: the is probably something like `avl_tree.o` that came with that header, you need to link with it

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks on windows

Comment: @sp2danny can you tell me how to link it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks

Comment: `process_vector` needs to operate on `V`, not `vector` (which is not a variable), and you should pass `V` by reference to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: How do you add functions.cpp and avl_tree.cpp to your project?

Comment: @QmickZh Im doing it using functions.h and avl_tree.h

Comment: You can't just add the header file, please add cpp file to your project.