# Linux - setting Code::Blocks to compile multithreading C++ code

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, codeblocks

I have searched through forums here, but nothing helped to the end in my case.
I'm trying to write and compile some C++ multithreading code in Code::Blocks 13.12, for now the only code I have is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void cpp11()
{
    std::cout<<"C++11 MULTITHREADING\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(cpp11);
    t.join();
}
```

Initially I could not compile and run that code (both in Code::Blocks and Terminal) because I was getting an error:

> Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what(): Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not
>   permitted.

I found that I'm able to compile and run that code calling g++ in the Terminal like that:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp -o Program
```

but I cannot set the same in Code::Blocks. 
I went to *Project -> Build options*, in the *Compiler settings* tab I selected **Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]**.
In the *Compiler settings -> Other options* I typed **-pthread**.
In *Linker settings -> Other linker options* I typed -**pthread**.
It does not work, after I build and run my project in Code::Blocks I get the same error message.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't have nothing like "Advanced options" in Build settings -> Compiler settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow instructions for this question

[How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

in the last step, when Add library dialog pops up type pthread.

**UPDATE**

Again go to build options > Compiler settings . click on other options and type -pthread

Comment: I just did like you advised - it did not help. pthread is added but is still gives me the same error.

Comment: @ikS11 can copy and paste commands that code blocks run to here? you can see them in build log.

Comment: Here you have the Build log's output after build and run:
Checking for existence: /home/dawid/MyProject/bin/Debug/MyProject
Executing: xterm -T MyProject -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/dawid/MyProject/bin/Debug/MyProject  (in /home/dawid/MyProject/.)
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))

Comment: Eh, some fun happened.... I changed the settings as you advised, but I did not change anything in the code, so the code was not build from the beginning... Works perfectly fine now after rebuild, thank you!