# Linker issue with EnumPrinters Sample

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, linker

First of all, I understand there are many topics on this function, but I did not find any about this particular problem, sorry if I am repeating...

I have been working on a program in C++ that works with printers and I need to get the list of printers in the system.

I am using the EnumPrinters API and I am getting a compile error I don't understand.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winspool.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    PRINTER_INFO_5 pi;
    PBYTE buffer[99];
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    DWORD bufferNeeded = 0;
    DWORD Entries = 0;

    bool r;

    r = EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS, NULL, 5, NULL, bufferSize, &bufferNeeded, &Entries);

    if (!r)
    { cout << "No printer found" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Found printers" << endl; }
}
```

When I try to compile (codeBlocks typical installation w/ gcc), I get this error:

```
C:\Programação\C++\lab\main.cpp 18 undefined reference to 'EnumPrintersA@28'
```

I think this may be a linker problem, but I don't know how to solve it...

Thank you!

SOLVED!

After some help I found out that the problem was that I wasn't importing the correct library. I thought including the header would be enough.

I needed to follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks) (using 'winspool' instead of 'gdi32').

By the way, adding 'winspool.lib' did not solve it. Use 'winspool' instead (no '.lib')

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linker is missing a `.lib`-file. If you lookup [`EnumPrinters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692(v=vs.85).aspx) at the MSDN documentation, you will see which library you have to add (somewhere at the bottom of the page, right before the comments).

In this case it's `Winspool.lib`. For gcc, add the [commandline](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) option: `-lwinspool`.