# C error: "Undefined reference to 'sf_open'" from libsndfile

Tags: c, header, codeblocks, undefined-reference, libsndfile

I am using Code::Blocks to test some codes, and I just can't biuld this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sndfile.h>

int main()
{
SNDFILE *sf;

sf = sf_open("file.wav",SFM_READ,&info); //error happens in this line

...
```

And the error is "undefined reference to `sf_open'", this not only happens to sf_open but also to any function from sndfile.h.

Actually here is what I did to get here:

- I've first downloaded and installed libsndfile for Windows x64 (I'm using Windows 10) from mega-nerd website, and tried to run this code...didn't work, the error this time was "sndfile.h: no such file or directory"
- So after a while I went to the installation dir (C:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\include) and copied the headers to the CodeBlocks defaut dir for headers (C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include), then I tried again and it finally found the header! But now this error is happening...

Sooo I guess I didn't open the header in the right way, I don't have much experience with this...I couldn't find the answer anywhere in the internet, I hope I get some luck here, thanks!

Comment: You need to link against libsndfile. [How to link against a library in Code::Blocks was previously described by Damon.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5881751/3415618)

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy stated, apart from include for sndfile.h, you have to link against the libsndfile library (it should be a .lib or .a file.

To link it just [follow the link he provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks/5881751#5881751)