# Integrate WireShark in my application

Tags: c, network-programming, wireshark

Can I integrate WireShark (as a command, or as system() command) into my C program in order to sniff all the received packets in my PC? I tried to use the NETCAT. but it doesn't work because the packets that I want to sniff are sent in an UDP multicast address: 224.1.1.113.

Comment: It would be easier to open a raw socket in monitor mode.

Comment: Would you explain to me how can i do that, because solutions like winpcap are hard for me to implement.

Comment: look into the answer regarding libpcap.  It's a much more portable way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool seems to have what you want

http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap

Also, here is a reference to wireshark CLI

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html

which has many options to do filtering so you can set it to the exact packet type you want.  You could invoke this command.

Here is a wiki reference to a multicast filter

https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/IPv4_multicast that you could use.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer, now I am working on the RawCap; I am using this command :
RawCap.exe –c 1 1 file.cap
to save only the first received packet from the wireless interface in file.pcap file.
After that I will execute this command from my program using system(‘RawCap.exe –c 1 1 file.cap’);
then i will open this file using fread and filter and extract the data.
Thank you again, best regards

Comment: These solutions are all standalone executables.  While this might be specifically what the questioner asked, I'd suggest that they are not good suggestions; why not suggest that the OP write his code properly with a library?

Answer (score 0):

You would be best served to utilize `libpcap` from within C.  This is the low level packet capture library that tools like Wireshark and TCPDump use to sniff the packets.

It is generally better to use a library than shelling out with `system()` or `exec()`.

Comment: Agree this is the proper long term solution and the original author should invest time to learn the libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i decide to try the winpcap library (thanks to your comments); i have succesfully instaled the library using this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673390/how-can-i-link-winpcap-in-code-blocks ; Now, i have to learn C++ first to start working on this library; thank you again; best regards

Comment: @tarekosis it's good practice to upvote answers that you find helpful.  Even the accepted answer could benefit from an upvote if you also found that helpful.

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have the wright to do this opperation, I need more than 15 reputation to do that. But, thank you a lot for all your attention and conderation.

Comment: Thank you so much mr. @DavidHoelzer. Your advice has change my everything.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of hard work; I made this program that is based on the tutorials of winpcap library; It captures the packets, filters them and plots the received data:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1999 - 2005 NetGroup, Politecnico di Torino (Italy)
 * Copyright (c) 2005 - 2006 CACE Technologies, Davis (California)
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 * documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. Neither the name of the Politecnico di Torino, CACE Technologies
 * nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote
 * products derived from this software without specific prior written
 * permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 */
#define HAVE_REMOTE
#include "pcap.h"
#include "winsock2.h "



/* 4 bytes IP address */
typedef struct ip_address{
    u_char byte1;
    u_char byte2;
    u_char byte3;
    u_char byte4;
}ip_address;

/* IPv4 header */
typedef struct ip_header{
    u_char  ver_ihl;        // Version (4 bits) + Internet header length (4 bits)
    u_char  tos;            // Type of service
    u_short tlen;           // Total length
    u_short identification; // Identification
    u_short flags_fo;       // Flags (3 bits) + Fragment offset (13 bits)
    u_char  ttl;            // Time to live
    u_char  proto;          // Protocol
    u_short crc;            // Header checksum
    ip_address  saddr;      // Source address
    ip_address  daddr;      // Destination address
    u_int   op_pad;         // Option + Padding
}ip_header;

/* UDP header*/
typedef struct udp_header{
    u_short sport;          // Source port
    u_short dport;          // Destination port
    u_short len;            // Datagram length
    u_short crc;            // Checksum
}udp_header;

/* prototype of the packet handler */
void packet_handler(u_char *param, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *pkt_data);


main()
{
pcap_if_t *alldevs;
pcap_if_t *d;
int inum;
int i=0;
pcap_t *adhandle;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
u_int netmask;
char packet_filter[] = "ip and udp";
struct bpf_program fcode;

    /* Retrieve the device list */
    if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs: %s\n", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Print the list */
    for(d=alldevs; d; d=d->next)
    {
        printf("%d. %s", ++i, d->name);
        if (d->description)
            printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
        else
            printf(" (No description available)\n");
    }

    if(i==0)
    {
        printf("\nNo interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter the interface number (1-%d):",i);
    scanf("%d", &inum);

    if(inum < 1 || inum > i)
    {
        printf("\nInterface number out of range.\n");
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Jump to the selected adapter */
    for(d=alldevs, i=0; i< inum-1 ;d=d->next, i++);

    /* Open the adapter */
    if ( (adhandle= pcap_open(d->name,  // name of the device
                             65536,     // portion of the packet to capture.
                                        // 65536 grants that the whole packet will be captured on all the MACs.
                             PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS,         // promiscuous mode
                             1000,      // read timeout
                             NULL,      // remote authentication
                             errbuf     // error buffer
                             ) ) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to open the adapter. %s is not supported by WinPcap\n");
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Check the link layer. We support only Ethernet for simplicity. */
    if(pcap_datalink(adhandle) != DLT_EN10MB)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nThis program works only on Ethernet networks.\n");
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
    }

    if(d->addresses != NULL)
        /* Retrieve the mask of the first address of the interface */
        netmask=((struct sockaddr_in *)(d->addresses->netmask))->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
    else
        /* If the interface is without addresses we suppose to be in a C class network */
        netmask=0xffffff;


    //compile the filter
    if (pcap_compile(adhandle, &fcode, packet_filter, 1, netmask) <0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to compile the packet filter. Check the syntax.\n");
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
    }

    //set the filter
    if (pcap_setfilter(adhandle, &fcode)<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nError setting the filter.\n");
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nlistening on %s...\n", d->description);

    /* At this point, we don't need any more the device list. Free it */
    pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);

    /* start the capture */
    pcap_loop(adhandle, 0, packet_handler, NULL);

    return 0;
}

/* Callback function invoked by libpcap for every incoming packet */
void packet_handler(u_char *param, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *pkt_data)
{
    struct tm *ltime;
    char timestr[16];
    ip_header *ih;
    udp_header *uh;
    u_int ip_len;
    u_short sport,dport;
    time_t local_tv_sec;

    /* convert the timestamp to readable format */
    local_tv_sec = header->ts.tv_sec;
    ltime=localtime(&local_tv_sec);
    strftime( timestr, sizeof timestr, "%H:%M:%S", ltime);

    /* print timestamp and length of the packet */
    printf("%s.%.6d len:%d ", timestr, header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);

    /* retrieve the position of the ip header */
    ih = (ip_header *) (pkt_data +
        14); //length of ethernet header

    /* retrieve the position of the udp header */
    ip_len = (ih->ver_ihl & 0xf) * 4;
    uh = (udp_header *) ((u_char*)ih + ip_len);

    /* convert from network byte order to host byte order */
    sport = ntohs( uh->sport );
    dport = ntohs( uh->dport );

    /* print ip addresses and udp ports */
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d.%d -> %d.%d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        ih->saddr.byte1,
        ih->saddr.byte2,
        ih->saddr.byte3,
        ih->saddr.byte4,
        sport,
        ih->daddr.byte1,
        ih->daddr.byte2,
        ih->daddr.byte3,
        ih->daddr.byte4,
        dport);
}
```