# How to use libpng in CodeBlocks on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, libraries, libpng

I have managed to install (I think) it with the setup provided by their website, but I have no idea what to do next. It created a folder called GnuWin32 in Program Files (x86) but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You need to link your library to your project. This is described here: [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial that actually tells you what you need to do step by step:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

I'll try to explain some stuff now that I understood it:

-GnuWin32 is a place where many libraries that you get from the internet will be installed

-it has a folder "lib" that includes the libraries and a folder "include" that has the header files

-codeblocks needs to be pointed to both of them, but from different places, be careful and go through the tutorial slowly (sorta ambiguous statement, yes, just follow the link)

-after this, once per project you need to include the .lib file for the library you want from the "lib" folder

I found this extremely confusing. In all honesty I expected that the .lib contains everything and you just drop it in a folder that codeblocks knows to check and you get it for all future projects but seems not.