# How to use libxd library with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, graphics2d

I find a good graphical library in c++, it's called libxd, very similar with Processing but I don't know how to install it in CodeBlocks or Visual Studio Code.

Link to this library : https://bernhardfritz.github.io/libxd/

Answer (score 0):

did you see the readme in the example  directory?
https://github.com/bernhardfritz/libxd/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md#windows

The library is already compiled for major systems, so you can extract the archive without compiling.
For Windows + CodeBlocks you have to link `.a` files (`glad`, `glfw3`, `xd`), see this answer [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

Comment: I added .a files but I get this error : https://postimg.cc/gallery/1cwrgkjfu/

Comment: You need to enable c++11 in code blocks. Search for that. I know there is a topic at StackOverflow about enabling c++11 in your IDE.

Comment: I tried that but I have another error : https://postimg.cc/Ty8MpJx8 , I used the terminal and I follow exactly the steps from the start page but I get this : https://postimg.cc/CBBqm0tn

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see @valentin, you're nearly at it but the precompiled lib is for x32 bit CPUs. Sometimes it does not matter, but here I guess you'll have to compile by yourself the library. Clone the original project, and type `cmake .` to compile the libraries.

Comment: If you want to compile the `libxd` project using the cmake, you'll have to run `git submodule init` and  `git submodule update` to download requirements. Depending your system (I'm on linux for my part), you'll possibly need bunch of dev libraries. So follow compiler errors or follow docs, good luck ;)