# How to use LAPACK and BLASE libraries in code::blocks?

Tags: codeblocks, lapack

My IDE is: Code::Blocks 20.03 ( compiler: mingw 9.2.0 )
My  OS is: Windows 10 Home 2004 x64

I intend to use `LAPACK` and `BLASE` libraries with gfortran programs.

I followed the instructions from the site: 
[icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#libraries](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#libraries)

Section: ***Build Instructions to create LAPACK and LAPACKE 3.5.0 dlls for Windows with MinGW***.

I used CMake according to the steps listed in the link I posted. I had no problems during the process itself.
The contents of the directory named lib after completion are:

[Lapack_lib_content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl4P1.jpg)

I try to find out on the internet and I follow the instruction from this question:

[stackoverflow?question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

I also read the instructions from the **code :: blocks manual**( including libraries, LibFinder...)...

After build and run I got this message:

[build_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynLeQ.jpg)

Is there a way to use the specified libraries in the specified IDE because I need them to solve certain problems from fitting data with a polynomial of a certain degree ( I do not have a money to use Intel MKL)?

Comment: Your title says `liblapack.dll` Your text says `liblapack.dll.a` Which **exact** files do you have? You did not answer that even in the discussion under your older question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288851/how-to-use-functions-from-lapack-and-blase-library-in-gfortran  I suggested to download the dill file from your link and you replied that you have it already. However, in your text you only mention liblapack.dll.**a** .

Comment: @VladimirF I made a change in the question itself. I did what you suggested to me but the result is the same.

Comment: What exactly did you write into the "Link libraries" dialog box?

Comment: BTW, this is the reason I avoid IDEs. It is so much easier to use the compiler in the command line.

Comment: @VladimirF This: (https://imgur.com/SBOre0h)

Comment: @VladimirF Sometimes avoiding a problem is the only solution to that problem but in this case I have no choice but to learn how to find a solution if there is one at all.

Comment: Show the Linker tab, not the compiler tag.

Comment: @VladimirF (https://imgur.com/HVAJDmi)

Comment: @VladimirF I found a solution. How can I publish it?

Comment: You van post an answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 0):

The following needs to be done.

1. step - follow the instructions from mentioned site in question ( downloading Lapack 
          3.9.0, creating `bin` and `lib` directories with CMake, cmd ...)
2. step - right click on project => build options => linker settings and adding all files 
          from `lib` directory, adding the path to `lib` in search directories tab..
3. step - it is necessary to copy all `.dll` files from `Lapack bin` to project 
          `bin\debug` ( `.exe` file is in `bin` )

After performing all the listed steps, it is possible to use certain procedures from the `Lapack` library in `code::blocks` projects ( `gfortran` )!